# Apache VirtualHost subdomain forwarding to Mercurial cgi script

Tags: apache, mercurial, cgi

I need to hook up my Mercurial server cgi script through an Apache VirtualHost subdomain along with authorization.

My apache is running on 80 and 91.
Apache is serving Mercurial through

C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.21\cgi-bin\hgweb.cgi
and is accessable through

http://my.com/cgi-bin/hgweb.cgi
and
http://localhost/cgi-bin/hgweb.cgi

All well and good, it serves perfectly there. My target is to subdomain it as:

http://hg.my.com/

with no trailing cgi-bin/hgweb.cgi

I have gotten the following URL to work with the config given below:

http://hg.my.com/cgi-bin/hgweb.cgi

... but it doesn't access the css and images properly (unlike above perfect service)

My config so far:

```
ScriptAlias /hg "/cgi-bin/hgweb.cgi"
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName hg.my.com
ServerAlias hg.my.com

#ScriptAlias / "/cgi-bin/hgweb.cgi"
#  <Directory />
#   Order Deny,Allow
#   Allow from all
#  </Directory>

#        ProxyPass /stylesheets !
#        ProxyPass /javascripts !
#        ProxyPass /images !

ProxyPassMatch ^.*/static(/.*\.css)$ http://localhost:91/cgi-bin/hgweb.cgi/static/$1
ProxyPassMatch ^.*/static(/.*\.js)$ http://localhost:91/cgi-bin/hgweb.cgi/static/$1
ProxyPassMatch ^.*/static(/.*\.png)$ http://localhost:91/cgi-bin/hgweb.cgi/static/$1
ProxyPassMatch ^.*/static(/.*\.gif)$ http://localhost:91/cgi-bin/hgweb.cgi/static/$1

ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://localhost:91/cgi-bin/hgweb.cgi
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:91/cgi-bin/hgweb.cgi
<Proxy *>
  #DirectoryIndex hgweb.cgi
    #ScriptAlias / /hgweb.cgi
# #  Order Allow,Deny
# #  Allow from all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    AuthUserFile C:\wamp\.htpasswd
    AuthName "Please Log In"
    AuthType Basic

    require user admin
    require user dev

 </Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
```

Obviously I am using the time honored google-trial-and-error approach and am out of my depth here.

Thus, my energetic egos mindless determinination for self-reliance, which otherwise seems to serve so well, now exhausted and filled with animosity toward the problem at hand -- brings me here, hat in hand, to ask:

"Brother, can you spare a dime?"

Answer (score 1):

Why run apache on both 80 and 91?  Is 91 just to serve up the static content?  Unless I'm missing one of your requirements you shoudl be able to do whatever you need with something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName hg.my.com

ScriptAlias / "/cgi-bin/hgweb.cgi"

<Location />
    Order Deny,Allow
    AuthUserFile C:\wamp\.htpasswd
    AuthName "Please Log In"
    AuthType Basic

    require user admin
    require user dev

</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

You shouldn't need a proxy, or separate rules for static (Mercurial will serve them up just fine).

Comment: I tried your code, but it was choking on the Location, so I went back step by step from the orig.conf and figured out how to do what I wanted -- but I had to put hgweb.cgi in the DocumentRoot. My intuition tells me this is a bad thing, what is the story?

Comment: As long as you have that ScriptAlias no files will be served from the document root anyway, but you could probably just use a <Directory> block to authorized access to that directory instead of using the DirectoryRoot.  What wasn't working about my Location tag.  I've not syntax checked it, but it's the best way to do this and should work.

Comment: Im using wamp and Apache 2.2.21 -- I didn't look in the logs, but it wouldn't boot. I am using `AddHandler cgi-script .cgi` and then `Options ExecCGI` on `<Directory "c:/wamp/www">`. I am not using a VH for hg.my.com since it seems to take me there for any subdomain that fails to match my other VHs -- which is a whatever for me. I imagine I could tweak it more now that I understand VH syntax a bit more. I had to "non-auth" other VH roots I had going on that occur later in the config -- am I to understand that the settings cascade down like that?

Comment: IF you're happy with how it works, you're done, but for any future searchers: The order of the virtual hosts defines the default, so make your "main" site last, and using ScriptAlias is preferable to an AddHandler because the later means an attacker that puts a .cgi in your DocumentRoot has compromised your system, whereas with a ScriptAlias they'd also need to alter your apache config, which is usually much harder.

Answer (score 1):

Just put a slash after the script: 
ScriptAlias /hg "/cgi-bin/hgweb.cgi/"